# MSChart and a Filled Radar Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, mschart

Can anyone tell me how to do a "Filled Radar" chart using MSChart?  I am able to create my charts and everything works great, but I want to create f Filled Radar like Excel, not the plain Radar.

I have searched high and low but cannot find any reference to the Filled Radar chart.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sample Environment for MSChart](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61) has an example of this:

```
// Populate series data
double[]    yValues = {65.62, 75.54, 60.45, 34.73, 85.42, 55.9, 63.6, 55.2, 77.1};
string[]    xValues = {"France", "Canada", "Germany", "USA", "Italy", "Spain", "Russia", "Sweden", "Japan"};
chart1.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

// Set radar chart type
chart1.Series["Default"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Radar;

// Set radar chart style (Area, Line or Marker)
chart1.Series["Default"]["RadarDrawingStyle"] = "Area";

// Set circular area drawing style (Circle or Polygon)
chart1.Series["Default"]["AreaDrawingStyle"] = "Polygon";

// Set labels style (Auto, Horizontal, Circular or Radial)
chart1.Series["Default"]["CircularLabelsStyle"] = "Horizontal";

// Show as 3D
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
```

Which renders the following image:

[image: Radar Chart]